# search for value in json and return the main key

Tags: javascript, json, web, destructuring

i have a json with structure like this

```json
{
  "india": {
    "north_states": ["TN", "AP", "MP", "AB"],
    "south_states": ["PB", "UP", "RJ", "HR"]
  },
  "us": {
    "north_states": ["AC", "AD", "AE", "AF"],
    "south_states": ["BA", "BB", "BC", "BD"]
  },
}
```

Now if I search for "UP", I have to get `south_states` and `india` as reply. how do i do that in JavaScript?

For example:

I need to get the country name based upon the input given in search. for example if i get the input value as 'UP' i need to search the json where UP is and get its key (south_states) and i also need to get the country name as india. the result should take the input of state acronym name and give both the keys as country name and the state_location(south or north)

Comment: Parse the JSON and recursively search the object.

Comment: What does mean 'UP'? What does mean `south_states` AND `india`? You expected to get `{india: {south_states: ["PB","UP","RJ","HR"]}}` How you want to get `us` and `north_states`?

Comment: i need to get the country name based upon the input given in search. for example if i get the input value as UP i need to search the json where UP is and get its key (south_states) and i also need to get the country name as india. the result should take the input of state acronym name and give both the keys as country name and the state_location(south or north)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Parse the JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) into a JS object that you can loop over.
2. [Loop over the main object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement), and then loop over each of those object's properties, and if any of those arrays [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the value you want to match, return the key of the main object, and the key of the inner object.

```js
const json = '{"india":{"north_states":["TN","AP","MP","AB"],"south_states":["PB","UP","RJ","HR"]},"us":{"north_states":["AC","AD","AE","AF"],"south_states":["BA","BB","BC","BD"]}}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

function check(data, val) {
  for (let key in data) {
    for (let innerkey in data[key]) {
      if (data[key][innerkey].includes(val)) {
        return [key, innerkey];
      }
    }
  }
  return 'No match';
}

console.log(check(data, 'UP'));
console.log(check(data, 'BO'));
console.log(check(data, 'AF'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate in this fashion:

*the code might need some tweaking, but it works.*

this uses recursion, to iterate the `JSON` to find the objects/array's that match. If the structure of the JSON is fixed, it could be even easier.

```js
const countries = { "india":{"north_states":["TN","AP","MP","AB"],"south_states":["PB","UP","RJ","HR"]}, "us":{"north_states":["AC","AD","AE","AF"],"south_states":["BA","BB","BC","BD"]}, };


function findItems(data, value, pkey){
  let results = [];
  for(let key of Object.keys(data)){
      let newData = data[key];
      if(typeof(newData) == 'string'){
          if(newData == value){
            results.push(pkey);
          }
      } else {
        results = findItems(newData, value, key).concat(results);
      }
  }
  if(results.length > 0 && pkey && results.indexOf(pkey) == -1){
    results.push(pkey);
  }
  return results;
}

let search = findItems(countries, 'UP');

console.info(search);
```

**For a fixed structure, and only on result should be found:**

```js
    const countries = { "india":{"north_states":["TN","AP","MP","AB"],"south_states":["PB","UP","RJ","HR"]}, "us":{"north_states":["AC","AD","AE","AF"],"south_states":["BA","BB","BC","BD"]}, };


    function findItems(data, searchTerm){
      let results = [];
      for(let country of Object.keys(data)){
          let stateGroups = data[country];
          for(let stateGroupName of Object.keys(stateGroups)){
            let stateGroup = stateGroups[stateGroupName];
            if(stateGroup.indexOf(searchTerm)!=-1){
              return [country, stateGroupName];
            }
          }
      }
     
    }

    let search = findItems(countries, 'UP');

    console.info(search);
```